# Why Substrate, Cumulus and Polkadot repositories are going to be merged into a mono-repo?

Tags: polkadot, cumulus

It might not be the best place to ask this question, but I'm not sure there are other place, especially since others could be interested in the answer.

Why do the 3 repositories (Cumulus, Substrate and Polkadot) are going to be merged into a single repo (Polkadot SDK) ?

I get that it is somehow "easier" to have all linked code in a single repo, but at the same time, some users/developers could want to just work with one of the project and not the other two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a discussion about it on the [Polkadot Forum](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/psa-parity-is-currently-working-on-merging-the-polkadot-stack-repositories-into-one-single-repository/2883/14)

Answer (score 1):

From https://polkadot-public.notion.site/Polkadot-SDK-FAQ-fbc4cecc2c46443fb37b9eeec2f0d85f

**Why are we merging the three interdependent repositories into one?**

Merging the interdependent repositories into a single repository will simplify the development process, eliminate the need for “companion” PRs across multiple repositories, and improve collaboration among team members. A single repository will also make it easier to manage issues, pull requests, and documentation.